# Online activation and purchase of Windows 10 using PPPOE and MS Store

Tags: windows-10, pppoe, software-activation, microsoft-store

I have installed a Windows 10 Home using media creation tool from Microsoft. Now I would like to activate it and purchase the valid key. So, I step into Parameters > Activation and select there a Go to Microsoft Store entry. The window with MS store page opens, but when I click on Buy option I get an error code 0x800713AB with a description "Internet Connection required".

[image: It says that I am not connected to Internet, but I am actually connected to it and opened a previous page!]

Obviously, I am connected to Internet.
But I am using a PPPOE connection which is rather good and MS store page can be opened in browser (although price there is different (higher), heh).

If this may be helpful, after boot I am connecting ("dialing") to my connection manually, this is fine for me. Another interesting feature: in Control Panel > Network and Internet I have a "no Internet Access" notice, but everything works fine. I was also able to install some application from MS Store,  although got the same error message, but it installed and worked.

**So, how do I get past the 0x800713AB error message and purchase the activation key with usage desktop version of Microsoft Store?**

Comment: See this....https://www.thewindowsclub.com/edge-store-apps-not-connecting-internet

Comment: @Moab - The link you provided isn't relevant to the author problem.  The link is with regards to  `0x80072EFD` and the other is getting `0x800713AB`

Comment: Yes but it is the same issue, shot in the dark.

Comment: Oh well... I have enabled IPv6 both in properties of my Ethernet adapter and in properties of my PPPOE connection, not helping.

Comment: I have also tried removing WinSock and WinSock2 sections in registry - that was a terrible idea, luckily I had restore point so I brought back my PPPOE connection to work. I also removed and recreated PPPOE connection - not helpful too.

Comment: But at the same time Windows is capable of running updates (recently had one)